# How do I load my shiny app dependent input csv files into shiny.io?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I launched my shiny app in shiny.io, but don't know how to load my csv files the app is dependent on. Usually it just is directed to the project wd and pulls in the csvs without an interactive button or anything-is this possible in the .io environment? If so, where and how do I upload my input csvs that are pulled into my app?
I'm trying to understand how to accomplish #1 bullet listed here (I think): https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217717347-How-do-I-load-data-for-my-apps-on-shinyapps-io-

Comment: You should select all files needed for the app when uploading to .io from rstudio.

Comment: I've been deploying using the deployApp() function, how do I do it this way? or are you suggesting deploying a different way?

Comment: I just deployed the folder where my app and all csvs live